# Django not reading JSON data passed through AJAX post request

Tags: python, json, django, ajax, post

I am sending an AJAX POST request using the following code (submitData is a JS Map):

```
var final_json_data = JSON.stringify(submitData);

    $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: POST_URL,
              data: { 'new-order-details': final_json_data },
              dataType: 'json'
          });
```

The view for this AJAX request is :

```
def post(self,request):
        new_order_details = request.body
        new_order_details = json.loads(new_order_details)
        return render(request,'home.html')
```

The error showing in python is :

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

What could be the error ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: `new_order_details = request.body.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: This is past in the POST requests, so `request.POST['new-order-details']`.